# firestore array not storing last value

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Registration form which has many fields for submission.Form submission is working fine, saving all the details to firestore. I have input file upload, user can select multiple files, on submit, uploadin all the files to firebase storage ans saving the upload link in an array(FileURLs).

For Example if I have selected 3 files on submit when i do console.log of state I can see the FileURLs with 3 data but In firestore last value is not getting saved.

Code

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const promises = [];
        const {fileURLs,sp_License}=this.state;
        let files=[];
        let orgFile='';
        let err = this.validate();
        if (!err) {
          this.setState({ loading: true,disChecked:false })
        //   this.fileupload();
        //   this.MultifileuploadHandler();
        const Lfilename = this.state.sp_Name + '_' + new Date().getTime();
        const uploadTask = storage.ref('License/' + Lfilename).put(sp_License);
        promises.push(uploadTask);
        uploadTask
        .then(uploadTaskSnapshot => {
            return uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        })
        .then(url => {
          //  orgFile.push({url});
            // this.setState({sp_License:url})
             orgFile=url
          //  console.log(orgFile)
        },()=>{
            console.log(sp_License)
        });

         //multi pilots file
         const storageRef = storage.ref();
         this.state.sp_PilotsLicense.forEach((file) => {
             const uploadTask= storageRef
                 .child(`License/${file.name}`).put(file)
                 promises.push(uploadTask);
                 uploadTask.then((snapshot) => {
                     return snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
                 }).then(url =>{
                     files.push({url});

                 })
         });

         Promise.all(promises).then(tasks => {
            console.log('all uploads complete');
            console.log(this.state)
             if(this._mounted)
            {
                console.log(orgFile)
                 this.setState({ 
                    fileURLs: files,
                    sp_License:orgFile,
                },()=>{
                    console.log(this.state)
                });
            }
            this.saveData();
        });


        }
    }
 saveData=()=>{
        let uid = this.props.auth.uid;
        let keysToRemove = ["loading", "checked", "disChecked", "open", "message"]
       let newState = Object.entries({...this.state}).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
         if(!keysToRemove.includes(key)){
             obj[key] = value
         }
         return obj
        }, {})
       console.log(newState)
        this.props.UpdateUserDetails(uid, newState,this.successMessage)
    }
```

Action

```
export const UpdateUserDetails= (id, droneSPDetails,func) => {
    console.log(droneSPDetails)
    console.log(func)
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirestore }) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore()
        firestore.collection('users')
            .doc(id)
            .set({
                 ...droneSPDetails,
                sp_RegisteredOn: new Date(),
                sp_Status:"pending",
                sp_ActiveFlag:"1",
            },{ merge: true })
            .then(() => {
                func();
                dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_DRONESP', droneSPDetails });

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
            });
    }
}
```

This is the value passed to store on firestore (from console.log)

```
fileURLs: Array(3)
0: {url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dronew…=media&token=084bc59a-8087-43de-afdb-05d4192ec4d2"}
1: {url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dronew…=media&token=3d427621-6a8b-4ed7-b6ce-5c3940fe7ee6"}
2: {url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dronew…=media&token=e24a5bab-e584-4a95-bb70-4d6c9f7fed7c"}
length: 3
```

but I can see only these 2 values getting saved.

[image: firebase data]

Comment: yrlv, Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please visit the link [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and elaborate your question by adding code and images.

Comment: can you please share your code here?

Comment: I don't see the code that actually works with Cloud Firestore, nor any usage of `fileURLs`.  Please edit to include it.